# Download a custom report into Excel on click of a custom button in lightning aura component

Tags: aura, custom-reports, lightning-button

I have a requirement, where i need to download a custom report in excel format once i click on a custom button in Lightning aura component.

Answer (score 0):

onclick of button call a javascript method and put below line of code into it will serve the purpose.
window.open('/reportId?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=xls');